# Closed Won email with account information

Tags: email, alert

I'd like to build a closed won email but, I've been asked to pull a field from the accounts object  'company registration number'

Here is what I've tried but it comes back blank:

Sales Won notification

Opportunity details:

Opportunity Number: {!Opportunity.Symity_Opportunity_number__c}

Opportunity Name/Topic: {!Opportunity.Name}

Full Revenue Amount: {!Opportunity.Amount}

More opportunity details here: {!Opportunity.Link}

Client Details:

Client Name: {!Opportunity.Account}

Client Number: {!Account.Company_registration_Number__c}

Account Manager: {!Opportunity.OwnerFullName}

**Client registration number: {!Account.Company_registration_Number__c}**

Comment: Are you using lightning email template or classic email template?

Comment: As per idea https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdifOUAR/cross-object-merge-fields-in-email-template it does not seem possible

Answer (score 0):

You could create a formula field on the opportunity object that contained {!Account.Company_registration_Number__c} and then reference it in the template.